# How to find which shared library exported which imported symbol in my binary?

Tags: linux, binary, reverse-engineering, elf, radare2

I am trying to find the shared library which imported an external symbol. Currently I can get all imported symbols by using nm or many alternatives such as using radare2. I can also get the libraries which the binary is dependent on by using ldd. However, I got stuck at this point since I cannot find an efficient way to get which external symbol in my binary is dependent on which shared library. So, for example how can I find the shared library which exports the function named foo or printf or anything in an efficient way? I provide an example:

```
        Output of nm -D myfile    
             w __cxa_finalize
             U foo
             w __gmon_start__
             w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
             w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
             U __libc_start_main
             U printf
             U puts

         Output of ldd
                linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd30904000)
libfoo.so => /home/user/Desktop/dynamic_link_example/libfoo.so (0x00007f1b08aaf000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1b088a1000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1b08abb000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, for example how can I find the shared library which exports the function named foo or printf or anything in an efficient way?

You can run your program with `env LD_DEBUG=bindings ./a.out`. This will produce a lot of output, which you can `grep` for `foo` and `printf`.

Note that the answer to "which external symbol in my binary is dependent on which shared library" is "whichever library defines this symbol first".

So if *today* your binary depends on `lifoo.so` for `foo` and on `libc.so.6` for `printf`, nothing stops you from running with a different `libfoo.so` tomorrow, and that different version of `libfoo.so` may define different symbols. If the new version of `libfoo.so` defines `printf`, that would cause the answer to your question for symbol `printf` to *change* from `libc.so.6` to `libfoo.so`.