# What C library provides memcpy?

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

How to figure out what gcc library provides the symbol for memcpy?

memcpy is provided by the header file , but I don't know what library provides the symbol.

```
$ objdump -ax libboost_filesystem.so | grep memcpy
0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000000              wmemcpy@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000000              memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14
```

It is clear that this shared object needs to find an implementation of memcpy.

How do I go about getting this information?
It would be nice if I can query the compiler.

Comment: The result of your search suggest that it is the GLIBC (which will be an implementation of the standard library) - what do you not like about that result?

Comment: What exactly do you need the information for? If you compiled everything correctly for the target system, there shouldn't be any issue linking with these symbols. If you are trying to mix code compiled for different targets (e.g. one using glibc and one using musl libc): It wont work.

Comment: A compiler cannot tell you because it doesn't know either. The name and location of the library could be anything and there is absolutely no connection to the header file. (Well, there are exceptions, and in the case of standard libraries this is in principle transparently provisioned as default settings and you don't have to care.)

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: I'm debugging a versioned symbol issue that is caused by linking a 3rd party library that was clearly compiled with a different version of gcc/g++.

I was wanting to know the exact library file from gcc that would provide the symbol memcpy. GLIBC was not specific enough.

I tagged it as C++, because I am working on a C++ project, however I admit that memcpy is inherited from C. I can remove that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what gcc library provides the symbol for memcpy?

The C standard library provides `memcpy`.

There are [some popular implementations of C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations), on Linux it is most notably glibc (well, and musl on Alpine Linux).

> How do I go about getting this information?

There are some approaches you can take. You can run something and see where it links to [How to find which shared library exported which imported symbol in my binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70488756/how-to-find-which-shared-library-exported-which-imported-symbol-in-my-binary)  . You can index all libraries on your system (see `man ld.so` and `/etc/ld.so.conf`) and index all symbols in those libraries and query the symbol ([this my script does that](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamilscripts/-/blob/master/bin/,ld_find_symbol#L8)). Then you can query your system package manager to find out to which package the shared library belongs to.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! When you say C standard library, does that imply the file libc.a on linux systems?

Comment: See `man libc`. Yes. But really shared library is used, `libc.a` is the statically linked version for linking statically.

Comment: I suppose there is also the possibility that `memcpy` could be implemented entirely in a macro so it would not appear as a function in the binary libraries at all.

Comment: @nielsen C allows that (I think), but C++ doesn't. It must be a function in C++, although the compiler could of course replace all calls to it with whatever else fits under as-if.

Comment: Finally found it!
```
$ nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep memcpy
000000000009f150 i memcpy
00000000000bb4d0 T memcpy
0000000000131a50 i __memcpy_chk
00000000000bd510 W wmemcpy
00000000001334a0 T __wmemcpy_chk
```

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy` is specified in the C standard as well as the POSIX standard, as well as a few other operating system specifications. Hence, it is provided by the C standard and/or the operating system library implementation.

The default standard library on a GNU system is the GNU C library aka glibc.

> How do I go about getting this information?

Search engines are good for getting information in general, including this one. Searching for `memcpy` should lead you to the information about what it is (a standard library function), and searching for your system's documentation should lead you to the information about its standard library implementation.

The `objdump` command that you demonstrated seems to also have shown you the answer.

> I'm trying to understand what is the file name in my system.

There's no standard way that applies to all systems. But let's assume that your operating system is Linux. The [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/libc.7.html) says

> The pathname /lib/libc.so.6 (or something similar) is normally a
> symbolic link that points to the location of the glibc library,
> and executing this pathname will cause glibc to display various
> information about the version installed on your system.

You can use `ldconfig -p | grep libc.so` to find the precise path.

Comment: the objdump command shows that the symbol is undefined.
I'm trying to understand what is the file name in my system where the memcpy symbol is provided.
There is no libglibc.so or libglibc.a

Comment: @WilderField The standard C library on linux is named libc,so.6 these days, no matter which implementation it is (usually glibc though)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ nm -D --with-symbol-versions /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep memcpy
000000000009f150 i memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14
00000000000bb4d0 T memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000131a50 i __memcpy_chk@@GLIBC_2.3.4
00000000000bd510 W wmemcpy@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000001334a0 T __wmemcpy_chk@@GLIBC_2.4
```